# Solving $\log_{2x}2 = \log_{3x}3$, I find that $x$ can be any number. Did I do something wrong?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given the question

> Find all possible values of $x$ when $\log_{2x}2 = \log_{3x}3$

This is how I did it..

$\log_{2x}2 = \log_{3x}3$

$1/ \log_2 2x = 1/ \log_3 3x$

Therefore $\log_2 2x = \log_3 3x$

$\log_2 2 + \log_2 x = \log_3 3 + \log_3 x$

$\log_2 x = \log_3 x$

$\frac{\log_2 x}{\log_3 x} = 1$

$\log_x x = 1$????

So x can be any number?

Can someone explain this a *pre-calculus* level? Thanks.

Comment: You have asked many questions here - so many that you should know by now to use mathjax. Until you do I can't figure out what the question is. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @EthanBolker Hello, do you know how to make make two variables as your base of log in MathJax? I couldn't find it on that site

Comment: use \log_{2x} produces $\log_{2x}$

Comment: OP: Can you confirm that my MathJax edit correctly captures your intention?  If so, then your error is in transitioning from $\frac{\log_2 x}{\log_3 x} = 1$ to $\log_x x = 1$.  I can't tell what you think you're doing there.

Comment: Hint: http://www.mathwords.com/c/change_of_base_formula.htm

Answer (score 4):

I do not know how do you obtain $\log_x(x)=1$.

From $\log_2 (x) = \log_3(x)$.

We have $$\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2} = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 3}$$

$$\ln x \left(\frac1{\ln 2} - \frac1{\ln 3} \right)=0$$

Hence $\ln x = 0$, hence $x=1$.

Comment: Hello, because any number like log_2(2) = 1 or log_1000(1000) = 1. So as long as the argument and base matches isn't it always 1?

Comment: but how does that has to do with the question? what happens to $\log_2$ and $\log_3$?

Answer (score 1):

How exactly did you perform the following step? It’s clearly not correct:

$$\color{red}{\frac{\log_2 x}{\log_3 x} = 1 \iff \log_x x = 1}$$

Instead, you must simplify as follows:

$$\frac{\log_2 x}{\log_3 x} = 1 \iff \frac{\frac{\ln x}{\ln 2}}{\frac{\ln x}{\ln 3}} = 1 \iff \frac{\ln x}{\ln 2} = \frac{\ln x}{\ln 3} \iff x = 1$$